ValueError: Exception encountered when calling Sequential.call()
I am working on GAN model for synthetic image generation.I am trying to train my discriminator but getting the above error.
Here is my code snippet:
   d_loss_fake = discriminator.train_on_batch(gen_imgs, fake)
   d_loss = 0.5 * np.add(d_loss_real, d_loss_fake)```

I am getting error in line
```d_loss_fake = discriminator.train_on_batch(gen_imgs, fake)```


I have tried reshaping fake by following line:
```fake = np.reshape(fake,(128,28,28,1))```

This raises another error: ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 128 into shape (128,28,28,1)

